# Alternative of coder.extrinsic in Simulink when running model on hardware

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi, simulink

I am using the following code in my Simulink model which is running on raspberry pi hardware:

```
coder.extrinsic('webwrite');  
 url = 'http://alnnovative.com/rts.alnnovative.com/security.php';
response = webwrite(url, "marium", "post");
```

When I searched through web, I found out that in external mode, code has to generated and coder.extrinsic does not generate code in external mode. So what alternative can I use in this case?

Answer (score 1):

if you have c-coded functionality which performs the same action on the target, you can switch using

```
coder.target
```

and directly call that c-functionality using:

```
coder.ceval
```

The documentation of `coder.ceval` provides an example:  https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017b/simulink/slref/coder.ceval.html

Comment: of course it';s dependencies need to be added to the compile options, but I am not aware of any limitations from the top of my head.